# How to add servlet JAR file permanently in Eclipse Oxygen instead of adding to each project?

Tags: java, servlets, eclipse-oxygen

Is there any solution to add a servlet JAR file permanently in Eclipse Oxygen instead of adding it to each project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe. But I would not recommend this approach, because you would bind yourself to the IDE, which is not a good practice. If someday you decide to switch to IntelliJ for example every project you will migrate will not work.

If your projects use the same JAR file(s) and you want to share it instead of redeclaring it everytime you need it you could evaluate other options, like creating a parent `pom.xml` file (if you are using Maven). In this way you can share consistently all your updated through various IDEs.

Comment: Thanks lore, yes you are right i am gonna use same oxygen setup in future for jsp, ejb other advanced java stuffs. thanks let me add for each project nothing wrong in that, i just got clear explanation for this thank you...!!